# The six letter word

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am a family.
>
> A member of me is so cute.
>
> Drawing my last four over my first two might perish this age.
>
> My counterpart makes a letter and a number.

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are a

> Feline

I am a family.

> I think the family of cats is [Felidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felidae) but can is also referred to by the adjective **feline**.

A member of me is so cute.

> [image]

Drawing my last four over my first two might perish this age.

> Drawing a **line** over **Fe** (iron) might perish this age - as clarified by the OP, this refers to $\overline{\text{Fe}}$, the anti-matter counterpart of iron which could cause us to perish (originally, I had thought this referred to the end of the **Iron Age** or the elimination of iron, in general).

My counterpart makes a letter and a number.

> My counterpart might be a **canine** or **K9**, for short.

Comment: I though of the last one as the answer!

Comment: Correct! Great job.

Comment: rot13(Gubhtu sbe gur yvar bire "Sr" guvat, V vagraqrq na bireyvar, vaqvpngvat gur nagvznggre pbhagrecneg bs veba.)

Comment: @DannyuNDos Ah, I see, makes sense.